# Smoothening a lineplot: Fix TypeError for interpolator1D y_axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to smoothen a lineplot with scipy.interpolate. However, for some reason I get an error with this method.

This my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.array([1348.4256 , 1342.99776, 1345.86432, 1352.97024, 1353.09312, 1355.0304])
y = np.array([232.2108 , 233.60184, 236.09988, 235.40544, 235.51776, 238.42728])

smooth = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, 'cubic')
y_range = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), 20)
plt.plot(smooth(y_range), y_range)


plt.plot(x, y, 
          linewidth=1)
plt.plot(smooth(y_range), 
          y_range)
plt.show()
```

The error I get is `TypeError: descriptor '_y_axis' for '_Interpolator1D' objects doesn't apply to 'interp1d' object`

My question is: what can I do to resolve this error and get a smooth plot over this line?

Answer (score 0):

Your `smooth()` function works fine within the limits of `min(x)` to `max(x)` and it returns `y` values for such operation. When you feed any value that falls beyond the limits, you will get error.

If you want to interpolate for `x` by specifying values of `y`, try this code:

```
smooth_for_y = interpolate.interp1d(y, x, 'cubic')
y_range = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), 20)
```

The interpolation:

```
smooth_for_y( y_range )
```

Output:

```
array([1348.4256    , 1344.64896129, 1342.64269324, 1342.09678777,
       1342.70123678, 1344.14603221, 1346.12116596, 1348.31662995,
       1350.4224161 , 1352.12851632, 1353.09777093, 1350.92268063,
       1345.07380415, 1337.3796737 , 1329.67182218, 1323.78178249,
       1321.54108752, 1324.78127019, 1335.33386338, 1355.0304    ])
```

Comment: I don't really get what you mean... How do get the output in such a way that I get a curved graph instead of a 'bulky' one? Now we have the smoothened y values, but I need x values in the same dimension. How do I get there?

Comment: @Robin_robin Let's forget this answer and check out my another try. I will delete this answer later on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution based on some assumptions (mentioned in the code).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# raw data
x = np.array([1348.4256 , 1342.99776, 1345.86432, 1352.97024, 1353.09312, 1355.0304])
y = np.array([232.2108 , 233.60184, 236.09988, 235.40544, 235.51776, 238.42728])

smooth_for_y = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, 'cubic')
x_range = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 20, endpoint=True)
y_smoothed = smooth_for_y( x_range )

# plot data as red dots
plt.scatter(x, y, linewidth=1, color="red")

# plot smoothed line across data
# assuming first point begins at xmin, ends at xmax, thus ...
#  ignoring the sequence of the original data
plt.plot(x_range, y_smoothed)

plt.show()
```

The plot:

[image: interp1d]